# 2500+ Duplicate Symbols for architecture armv7 - Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just got this interesting error by upgrading to Xcode 8. It worked fine in Xcode 7. However, in Xcode 8 it gives me a linker error:

```
ld: 2562 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Frameworks I'm using:**

[image]

**Frameworks search path:**

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/My\ App
```

**Linker Flags:** (Obj-C)

```
$(inherited)
```

I'm not using pods. I've just copied over the frameworks to the project directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode recommended to use warning flags and set `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS` to `YES`.

Setting it back to `NO` solved the problem!

Comment: I had similar problem but I had to revert all Xcode 8 recommended settings to get back on track.