# Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 Duplicate Symbol in the same file

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift2

I upgrade my code form Xcode 7 and Swift 2.2 to Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3. 
Everything is fine in Xcode 7 but some error came out in Xcode 8.

Here's some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its seems like I reference a file twice but, when I unference once, and console that can not find class in the file.

Any ideas?

Here's my Link Binary screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Try the proposed solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542107/2500-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-xcode-8?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: @Anubis, Thanks, but still can not work for me.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39527516/4593553)

Comment: This patch work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39641411/2128941